# Can't install Internet Explorer on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to install IE 9 but it says I have already installed the latest IE version, while I have no internet explorer installed. Instead, there is an update called Windows Internet Explorer 9 **which fails to uninstall**. So how do I install IE 9?

System Update Readiness Tool for Windows never fixes the issue.

Windows 7 x64 SP1. Never had IE 9. Not listed in Windows Features. Was deleted from the iso image.

Re-installing is not an option.

What I actually need is to integrate a webBrowser control in my .NET application. It's working fine (although i have no IE), but the flash player works extremely bad.

Comment: Are you sure internet explorer isn't installed, have you tried running iexplore.exe?

Comment: yep. there's no iexplore.exe

Comment: Which error do you get when trying to uninstall the "IE9 update" ?

Comment: not all of the updates were successfully uninstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you never installed IE9 Beta ?

Some ideas :

1. [Perfect Uninstaller](http://www.perfectuninstaller.com/) is claimed to be able to uninstall IE9 using the "Force Uninstall" option.
   It is interesting to see whether it will see IE9 as installed on your computer, or not.
2. You could try all the seven methods described in [Methods to Uninstall / Remove IE9](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/methods-to-uninstall-remove-ie9/e28fba17-245a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).
3. If the problem is with Windows update, see the article [Windows Update Troubleshooting](http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/windows-update-troubleshooting/), and starting with how to delete the SoftwareDistribution folder.

Comment: Not beta. I have never had IE browser.

Comment: IE was always installed on your computer, since it is always installed - just the user interface was hidden. IE is the same as the webBrowser control.I suggest to go thru my 3 points, even for a negative feedback, so I can better understand your problem.

Comment: 1. perfect unistaller shows nothing about ie. 2,3 - tried them all, still not able to uninstall.

Comment: You cannot uninstall IE any more than you already did. This is certainly looking more and more like [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: yep i do understand that i can't uninstall it more than i already did. but i also can't INSTALL an IE browser because it says i have already the newest version

Comment: Repair Install will only refresh Windows and will not interfere with other applications and settings. However, make sure that you have full backups and installation disks + serials for all your applications. The Windows installation DVD should have the exact same service-pack as is installed. The best protection is to take an image of your system drive on an external disk with a 3rd-party disk backup product that has a boot CD (and test before starting that it does boot and can see the image on the external disk).

Comment: okay i can reformat and do a clean install but i don't want as i have optimized at maximum this build, to have the best performance etc. i'll try to repair install. how do I do that?

Comment: The link I posted an hour ago has a very good step-by-step explanation with screenshots.

Comment: oh yes didn't notice that. i'll try it and i'll post the results

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel (icon view) and click Programs and Features, when it opens go to the left side and click "Turn Windows Features on or Off"

Be sure IE9 has a tick in the box. Tick it and hit OK if it is not ticked.

[image]

Comment: no internet explorer here. i have never had ie installed.

Comment: Do any IE versions show in that window? Windows 7 comes with IE by default when it is originally installed.

Comment: yeah but I have modified the iso and i have deleted some features like internet explorer, games and others

Comment: I suggest you use an unmodified iso, then.

Comment: Try a repair install with an unmodified ISO, or a modified one with IE but everything else you want gone. Repair install will keep all your data and installed programs, just reinstalling the base OS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the ISO to include IE. Then while installing choose to upgrade not to reinstall. This will solve your problem I hope.